# Accessing a Global Hashtable from Concurrent Threads (Common Lisp)

Tags: multithreading, common-lisp, hashtable, sbcl

I cannot find the bug related to the global hash-table in the following SBCL code:

```
(defparameter *lci-hash-table* (make-hash-table :size 10000))  
  "Hash-table key = length|char|index concatenated together (eg, 5A0),
   hash-table values = list of matching symbols (eg, (ABATE ABBEY ...))."

(defun dictionary-compatible ($new-cross-str)  ;eg, "A     " of length 5
  "Tests if a string (with uppercase alphabetic and space characters)
   is compatible with the dictionary words (symbols) in a hash-table."
  (iter (with len = (length $new-cross-str))
        (for char in-sequence $new-cross-str)
        (for index from 0)
        (when (not (eql char #\Space))
          (collect (gethash (ut::intern-symbol len char index)  ;this gethash
                            *lci-hash-table*) into dict-words)) ;always returns nil
        (finally (return (reduce #'intersection dict-words)))))

(defun intern-symbol (&rest args)
  "Interns a symbol created by concatenating args.
   Based on symb in Let Over Lambda."
  (flet ((mkstr (&rest args)
           (with-output-to-string (s)
             (dolist (a args) (princ a s)))))
    (values (intern (apply #'mkstr args)))))
```

The function `dictionary-compatible` above runs fine in single-threaded mode in SBCL. But starting over with a new image in multi-threaded mode (using the :lparallel library) the gethash access to the global `*lci-hash-table*` always returns NIL.

The `*lci-hash-table*` is only being accessed, never updated, and therefore, according to the SBCL manual, there is no need to make it :synchronized, or defined with sb-ext:defglobal.

I think I'm missing something that's related to multi-processing for hash-tables in SBCL.

Edit: For background info, here is the code to populate the hash-table:

```
(defun create-lci-ht (dictionary-file)
  "Read dictionary words (symbols) from a file into strings
   and store in a lci hash table."
  (with-open-file (infile dictionary-file :direction :input :if-does-not-exist nil)
    (when (not (streamp infile)) (error "File does not exist!"))
    (with-open-file (stream dictionary-file)
      (let ((word-strings (uiop:read-file-lines stream)))
        (iter (for word-string in word-strings)
              (for word-length = (length word-string))
              (while word-string)
              (iter (for char in-sequence word-string)
                    (for index from 0)
                    (push (intern word-string)
                          (gethash (ut::intern-symbol word-length char index)
                                   *lci-hash-table*))))))))
```

Comment: How do you populate the hash-table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code exhibits two classic mistakes in CL: mistakes which everyone, including me, has made at some point!

**The first mistake** is that you are explicitly creating and looking up symbols in a package *without ever specifying the package*, so you are simply relying on whatever the ambient value of `*package*` is when the code is running.  That's, at the very least, fragile.

- `(in-package ...)` in a source file sets the package during the time the code in the file is being compiled and loaded but *not* the ambient package outside the dynamic extent of the compilation / loading, since both `load` and `compile-file` rebind `*package*` to its ambient value.
- Macros like `with-standard-io-syntax` rebind `*package*`.
- The behaviour of `*package*`, and special variables in general, with multithreading is implementation-dependent and shims like Bordeaux Threads do not (and probably can not!) hide this.

As an example of the last point, consider this code:

```
;;; Assume Bordeaux threads is loaded
;;;

(defpackage :one
  (:use :cl :bordeaux-threads))

(defpackage :two
  (:use :cl :bordeaux-threads))

(in-package :one)

(start-multiprocessing)

(defun test (p1 p2)
  (setf p1 (find-package p1)
        p2 (find-package p2))
  (let ((*package* p1))
    (multiple-value-bind (tp1 tp2)
        (join-thread
         (make-thread
          (lambda ()
            (values *package*
                    (setf *package* p2)))))
      (values (package-name tp1) (package-name tp2)
              (package-name *package*)))))
```

Now in SBCL:

```
> (test :one :two)
"COMMON-LISP-USER"
"TWO"
"ONE"
> (test :one :two)
"TWO"
"TWO"
"ONE"
```

Yes: different results!

In LW:

```
> (test :one :two)
"ONE"
"TWO"
"ONE"
> (test :one :two)
"ONE"
"TWO"
"ONE"
```

I don't understand SBCL's behaviour but I also have not read a lot of SBCL's manual in detail.  I think what is probably happening is that in SBCL threads do not inherit special bindings, and `*package*` is bound somewhere in the REPL thread: this means that the assignment in the thread is to the global value of `*package*`.  In LW threads do inherit their parent's bindings I think.

The way of resolving this is to always be specific about what package you are using if you are calling functions like `intern`.  This is what is actually breaking your code.

**The second mistake** is that you are using packages to map strings to symbols *and then using a hashtable to map symbols to values*.  In other words:

1. you are looking up a string in a package, which is an object whose job is to map strings to symbols, which are objects which, among other things, have values and properties;
2. you are then looking up the symbol you found in a hashtable, which is an object whose job is to map objects to values.

OK, think about that: you're doing *two lookups* to get the value you're after.  Instead, do one:

- either look up the string in a package and then simply use the value of the resulting symbol;
- or, and almost certainly better, look up the string in an `equal` hashtable directly.

The first approach is essentially just using a package as a hashtable: this is fine so long as you are careful that this is *all* you use it for (so make sure you don't use it for the symbols which make up your program as well!), but it's ugly for two reasons:

- packages are not completely first-class in CL, and in particular you can't have anonymous packages, so you end up having to be careful about names.
- symbols tend to be rather heavyweight objects in CL implementations, with a bunch of slots of which you are using only one -- they don't have to be but they often are.

So generally, if what you want is a map from strings to values, where those strings are not the names of parts of your program, the best approach is just to use an `equal` hashtable for this.

---

If you really do need to use a package for some reason, and you want `intern-symbol` to take an unknown number of arguments, then probably you want `intern-symbol` either to take the package as its first argument:

```
(defun intern-symbol (package &rest args)
  (intern (format nil "~{~A~}" args) package))
```

Or you might provide an explicit variable

```
(defvar *my-hashtable-package* (make-package "MY-HASHTABLE-PACKAGE" :use '()))

(defun intern-symbol (&rest args)
  (intern (format nil "~{~A~}" args) *my-hashtable-package*))
```

As a final note: `intern-symbol` is not reliable in general:

```
> (eq (intern-symbol 1 23) (intern-symbol 1 2 3))
t

> (eq (intern-symbol 1 23) (intern-symbol 1 "2" 3))
t
```

Of course it may be fine in constrained cases.

Comment: Nice--thank you for such an informative & insightful piece. Given this background, it looks like the straightforward approach of using an equal hash-table is worth checking. Originally I was worried about equal having to eql compare each individual character in a string, but maybe the unintended overhead you mention is worse.

Comment: @davypough: yes, that's the cause of the second mistake (or it has been for me).  But then you realise that *a package has to do that too*: the only way a package knows if a string corresponds to a symbol in it is by doing a per-character check on the string at least once (and maybe twice: compute some hash, then compare what is in that bucket with the string in case there's a hash collision).

Comment: isn't the condition on "strings" in *"if what you want is a map from strings to values, where those strings are not the names of parts of your program, the best approach is just to use an equal hashtable for this"* unnecessary? It would be so when using the packages, as you discuss above that point in the answer. (I haven't read the question, though).

Comment: @WillNess: what I was trying to get at was that you might *need* to get symbols because (for instance) you're writing some kind of reader or something and you want to be able to interact with what CL thinks are names for parts of the program.  But if you don't need that, strings and a hashtable are fine I think (although somewhat historically heretical).  I probably did not put it terribly well.

Answer (score 1):

The general problem is localized to the hash-table access point `(gethash (ut::intern-symbol len char index) *lci-hash-table*)`, which always returns NIL, even though the hash-table is visible in threads, and the hash-table keys (symbols--eg, 5A1) are verified correct. Note that the access is probably better rendered as `(gethash (intern (format nil "~D~C~D" len char index)) *lci-hash-table*)`, but this makes no significant difference.

The specific problem seems to be with the hash-table keys. Evidently, the keys installed during hash-table creation, are different than the keys (with the same symbol name) when they are accessed. My guess is that the difference may be due to different package names. (The project package is called :ww). Changing the access point to `(gethash (intern (format nil "~D~C~D" len char index) :ww) *lci-hash-table*)` fixes the problem.

It is still unclear to me how the hash-table key references could be in different packages, since everything is loaded into the one package :ww (all files begin with `(in-package :ww)`). It is also unclear why the extra package reference is not needed for single-threaded runs, but is needed for multi-threaded runs.

Comment: Ok I know, see edit (maybe)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using only a global binding for `*lci-hash-table*`, not local rebindings, so as far as I know the same value should be visible from all threads. If you observe different values of `*lci-hash-table*` from different threads then it would be a case of special variables having thread-local storage, but here I think this is not your problem.

The variable is bound to `nil` in your case when *you start over with a new image in multi-threaded mode*, so I would start trying to debug that instead. I would add `(break)` in both `create-lci-ht` and `dictionary-compatible` near the `gethash` to see when both instructions are executed. Apart from that I don't really know how to identify your problem.

--- Edit

You might in fact have a problem of having special variables being bound to different values in different threads, but for the `*package*` variable: you can check that by showing which package is active during the `break` and/or forcing the package to be a specific value in `intern`: `(intern str package)`.

That would explain why your hash-table with an equality test of `eql` doesn't find matches for symbols (you can try to add `:test #'equal` to `make-hash-table` but that is probably not a change you want to keep after debugging).

Comment: Thank you so much for spending time studying this, and providing a different perspective. I think I now understand what's going on, but why is still beyond my ken (see tentative answer below).

Comment: Per your suggestion, I looked at `*package*` at several places. Everything is initially defined and loaded in package :ww. Then the program is run while still in :ww. But somehow `*package*` shows :cl-user while running and accessing the hash-table. This only occurs while running multi-threaded, never when single-threaded. There is no programmatic change to :cl-user. Go figure!?

Comment: You are using lparallel, it might be important to check how and when the kernel is created; you can also define a worker context to make sure some special variables are always properly established in each thread

Comment: Yes, worth checking: the kernel is created in the proper project package :ww, but there are some unshared special variables in each thread. However, the special variable in question `*lci-hash-table*` is defglobal; no problems detected with the thread-internal ones.